# Jaxb xml Map as list elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am having trouble creating Java classes for the following XML:

```
<Users>
    <User id="1">
        <Name>Test</Name>
    </User>
    <User id="2">
        <Name>Test2</Name>
    </User>
</Users>
```

I am using Jaxb (javax.xml) with a **Users** class containing a map of **User** object (Map where String is the user id). In this example **User** contains Id and Name, where Id is an attribute to the **User** element and Id is an element in **User**.

I have looked on [some examples](https://sushantworld.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/jaxb-custom-xml-to-java-map-using-xmladapter/) but all the examples and guides are focusing on having a root element surrounding **Users** (see below).

```
<Database>    
    <Users>
        <User id="1">
            <Name>Test</Name>
        </User>
        <User id="2">
            <Name>Test2</Name>
        </User>
    </Users>
</Database>
```

Is it possible to remove the root element **Database** and just have **Users** with many **User** elements inside?

Comment: How do you keep the `User` objects stored in a `Users` object ?

Answer (score 0):

An adapter would convert between a Users with a List (what JAXB can handle) and a UsersMap with a Map, but it would have to be rigged up for a field - hence the additional level around Users.

You can (with a little extra effort) hold a map and a list in your class and let JAXB work on the list. Before marshalling and after unmarshalling, conversion methods need to be called, but the application can use the map.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Users")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FieLD)
public class Users {
    @XmlElement( name = "user", required = true )
    private List<User> user = ...
    public List<User> getUser(){...}
    @XmlTransient
    private Map<Integer,User> id2user = ...
    public void putUser( User user ){ ... }
    public User getUser( Integer is ){ ... }

    public void map2list(){...}
    public void list2map(){...}
}
```